# ACF - How can I get all the fields of a field group

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have multiple fields on a field group called **Membership Level Feature** and which post id is 5112. Now, I want to get all the fields of this post id. I am using:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r( get_fields(5112 )  );
echo '</pre>';
```

But getting empty :(

Please check this image:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if (function_exists('acf_get_field_groups')) {
    $acf_field_group = acf_get_field_group(5112);
    $acf_fields = acf_get_fields(5112);
}
```

Comment: This `acf_get_field('select_this_membership_level_feature')` works for me :)\

Comment: Good to hear! if you found this helpful, please mark the answer as accepted so that other people can easily find it in the future :)